# Calculate the maximum value of a function using a list comprehension

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a function using a list comprehension to calculate the maximum value of a function:

```
f(x)=x^3-x^2+3x+2 on the interval [4,12].
```

To define the function:

```
mymax(f, a, b, precision)
```

where precision is the precision in the value of x where the maximum occurs.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming a, b are the ends of your interval and precision is the increment, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

def f(x):
  return x**3-x**2+3*x+2

def mymax(f, a, b, p):
  max_x=float('-inf')
  for x in np.arange(a,b,p):
     max_x=max(max_x,f(x))
  return x
```

OR, a in a nice one-liner:

```
def mymax(f, a, b, p):
   return max(y for y in [f(x) for x in np.arange (a,b,p)])
```